# Suppressing "sudo: sorry, a password is required to run sudo"

Tags: bash, sudo

I am trying to test if a user has the required sudo rights to run a command as another user without providing a password. What I have is this

```
 sudo -u other-user -n true
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: You don't have the neccessary sudo rights"
  else
    echo "OK. You do have the neccessary sudo rights"
  fi
```

However, the scripts prints this error message if sudo requires a password

```
  sudo: sorry, a password is required to run sudo
```

Is it possible to suppress this error message?

I have tried to redirect both system err and system out but the error message still appears.

```
  sudo -u other-user -n true > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: `sudo -u other-user -n true 2>/dev/null`  sends standard error to nothing, `null` binary.  A similar situation which I've described here:  http://serverfault.com/questions/550107/why-is-cron-mailing-me-program-output-even-though-ive-redirected-to-dev-null/550120#550120

Comment: Thanks. Now i wonder why not "> /dev/null 2>&1" didn't also send standard error to nothing, but thats another question ...

Comment: `sudo -n true >/dev/null 2>&1` works perfectly fine for me (immediately returns status 1 & nothing is displayed). What version of sudo, and distro are you using?

Comment: Normally that should have worked. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055?highlight=%282%3E%261%29|%28%3E%2Fdev%2Fnull%29 which explains everything about file descriptors including portability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way works nicely for me:

```
$ sudo -u test -n true  
sudo: a password is required
$ echo $?                                   
1
$ sudo -u test -n true >/dev/null 2>&1
$ echo $?                                   
1
```

But if for whatever reasons it does not help for you, try these:

```
$ { sudo -u test -n true ; } >/dev/null 2>&1
$ echo $?                                   
1
$ ( sudo -u test -n true ) >/dev/null 2>&1
$ echo $?                                 
1
```